# .NET program run on Any CPU vs x86

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, activex

I have two C# projects say A and B, and project A uses an ActiveX control, and project B will reference project A.

The problem is that A with the ActiveX control is only able to run on x86 platform (namely, in Visual Studio project config, we can change platform to either Any CPU or x86), and it turned out that B also needs to run on x86 once it references A. This is problematic as it may affect many other things in project B.

I was wondering is there any way to work around this limitation and run all the projects on Any CPU? Or at least stop project B (calling projects) from being changed to x86?

Many thanks

Comment: Apart from the technical feasability, it would not make much sense to have something compile to AnyCPU that then won't *run* on any CPU. This seems to be an [XY-Problem-Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). Can you ask the quesion that's actually troubling you? What problems do you have when using x86 for project B?

Comment: @nvoigt the problem is project B is a large, existing legacy code that I am not allowed to change. Now I am adding some new functionality through project A to B.

Comment: It ought to be a bit obvious.  Get on the phone and call the vendor of the component, ask for the 64-bit version.  If he doesn't pick up or says no then replace it with something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In project A, you can code this to allow project B to be turned into Any CPU:

```
// ActiveXClass methods
static void MyActiveXControlCode() {
    // ActiveX Control code
}

public static void Publisher() {
    MyActiveXControlCode();
}
```

In project B, you code:

```
using ProjectA;
namespace ProjectB {
    public class EntryClass {
        public static void Main() {
            ActiveXClass.Publisher();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Luís do you mean put everything in static methods ? Please could you explain the reason behind? Thanks

Comment: @wuha I'm using static methods because I don't need an instance of the `ActiveXClass` to do the ActiveX related stuff.